# Setting a max and min value for user number input in console

Tags: c#, constraints, console-application, user-input

```
Console.WriteLine("     **************************************");
Console.WriteLine("     ****** Reviewer Awarding Points ******");
Console.WriteLine("     **************************************");
Console.WriteLine();
string[]properties= { "Clarity", "Orginality", "Difficulty" };
        
int[] a = new int[3];
int[] b = new int[3];
        
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("     ***" + properties[i]+"***");
    Console.Write(" Alice:   ");
            
    a[i] = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    if(a[i]>100 || a[i] < 1)
        Console.Write("   Bob:   ");
    b[i] = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine();
}
Console.Read();
}
```

I want user to enter a value between 1 and 100(including 1 and 100).So what I am gonna do?

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear
try

```
   int value;
   do{
   Console.Write("Enter a value");
   value=int.parse(Console.ReadLine());
   }while(value<1 || value>100);
```

Comment: Your answer also isn't especially clear. Can you [edit] it to include an explanation of how you understood the problem, and why your code solves it?

Comment: I thought he/she wanted to get a value between 1 and 100 and the user should not proceed if the value is not between 1 and 100.

Answer (score 0):

Make a method that checks the result for being in range:

```
public int AskInt(string question, int min, int max){

  while(true){
    Console.WriteLine(question);
    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    if(int.Tryparse(input, out int value) && value >= min && value <= max) 
        return value;
  }
}
```

The only way to escape the loop is to enter a valid number that is in range, otherwise the question just repeats

Then you can use it multiple times in your code:

```
int age = AskInt("Enter an age between 10 and 100: ", 10, 100);
int weight = AskInt("Enter a weight between 100 and 350: " 100, 350);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```cs
if(a[i]>=100 || a[i] <= 1)
```

You can learn about C# operators at this site: https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_operators.php